# How do I get the current catageory id?

Tags: php, xml, variables, layout, magento

I have a CMS page that I am going to display products on with the following updated XML code:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list"  name="product_list" template="catalog/product/wholesale-list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>191</category_id></action>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I have tried getting the ID I set in the layout, but no such luck. I have tried:

```
$_category = Mage::registry(‘current_category’);
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
```

and

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/layer’);
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
```

But neither of these methods work. Does anyone know how I can get the ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tried this, but maybe something like:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->getCategoryId()
```

This way you are directly getting the variable that you have set on the Block object in the XML.

Cheers,
JD

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Day, It is working for me.

`Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();`

this function does not works when we calls products from cms page or cms static block.

Answer (score 39):

i think this is the best way ;)

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such :)

Comment: @ShivSingh basically above script to get last visited category

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
 Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered updating the layout of the catalog page rather than making a CMS page?  I suppose there are situations where you might prefer a CMS page, but you can update the layout of a category fairly easily, well about as easy as it gets in Magento, which isn't all that easy :)

Login to the admin backend, go to Catalog -> Manage Categories,  then choose the category you want, then click the Custom Design tab.  Notice the Custom Layout Updates field.  This is where you can put your layout updates.

So for this category, if you didn't want to display a specific block you could do something like

```
<reference name="right">
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
</reference>
```

Which would remove the block named right.permanent.callout from the layout altogether.  And if you wanted to just change the product listing to use your specific phtml file you could do something like...

```
<reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/wholesale.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

You can probably use google to find out more about how to layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$currentCat = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products')->getCurrentCategory();
```

Then you have the current category as an object and you can get the id by:

```
$currentCat->getId();
```